# Can't load data into Jena - Fuseki

Tags: jena, fuseki

I'm using Docker to host a Jena/Fuseki container.  I have a very outdated Fuseki instance on another server that I would like to migrate the data from.  I've backed up the old server into a .nq file, but I can't create a new datastore with this file.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:10

ENV JENAVERSION=3.7.0
ENV FUSEKI_HOME=/fuseki


RUN mkdir /fuseki
RUN mkdir /jena

RUN wget http://apache.claz.org/jena/binaries/apache-jena-fuseki-$JENAVERSION.tar.gz -P /tmp \
    && tar -zxvf /tmp/apache-jena-fuseki-$JENAVERSION.tar.gz -C /tmp \
    && mv -v /tmp/apache-jena-fuseki-$JENAVERSION/* /fuseki

RUN wget http://apache.claz.org/jena/binaries/apache-jena-$JENAVERSION.tar.gz -P /tmp \
    && tar -zxvf /tmp/apache-jena-$JENAVERSION.tar.gz -C /tmp \
    && mv -v /tmp/apache-jena-$JENAVERSION/* /jena

EXPOSE 3030

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/fuseki/fuseki-server"]
```

Docker-Compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:

fuseki_test:
    build:
        context:  /docker/buildfiles/
        dockerfile: /docker/buildfiles/fuseki
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
        -   "19095:3030"
    volumes:
        - "/docker/jena2/databases/data:/run/databases/PDE_PROD"
        - "/docker/jena2/backups:/run/backups"
        - "/docker/jena2/shiro.ini:/run/shiro.ini:ro"
        - "/docker/jena2/fuseki-tdb2.ttl:/run/config.ttl:ro"
        - "/docker/data:/staging"
    environment:
        - ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
        - JVM_ARGS=-Xmx16g
```

Here's the command I used to try to load the data:

```
/bin/bash /jena/bin/tdb2.tdbloader --loc=/run/databases/PDE_PROD /staging/PDE_DEV_2_2018-02-15_12-51-30.nq
```

Everything loads without errors, the data shows up in the folder I would expect, no errors starting Fuseki, but no triples show up.

Comment: That is an N-Quads file. Maybe all the data is in named graphs and youlooked in the default graph? Try "SELECT * { { ?s ?p ?o} UNION { GRAPH ?g { ?s ?p ?o } }"

Comment: No, I set up both graphs.  There's nothing weird going on.  In fact, I can migrate the data using the TDB1 version of tdbloader.